# Darknet multithreading with pexpect

Tags: python, multithreading, spawn, pexpect, darknet

I'm trying to do parallel processing of 4 images using Darknet and Pexpact.
The current implementation is similar to this test. It takes 70ms to detect one image, while 300ms is needed to detect 4 in parallel. Am I doing it wrong or do I need more than 1GPU for this processing.

```
class Darknet: 
  def __init__(self): 
      self.instance = pexpect.spawn(f'darknet detector test {config.OBJ_DATA} {config.YOLOV3} {config.WEIGHTS} -ext_output -dont_show')
      self.instance.delaybeforesend = None
      self.instance.delayafterread = None
      self.instance.expect('Enter Image Path:')
      self.available = True

  def process(self, image_name): 
      self.instance.sendline(image_name)
      self.instance.expect('milli-seconds.', timeout=600)
      self.instance.expect('Enter Image Path:', timeout=600)
      output = self.instance.before
      logging.info(output)

      return output


class PexpectPerformanceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pexpect_speed(self):
        image_path = "/app/tmp/training_set/125_20231113_100730_609_3.jpg"
        darknet_instance_1 = SimpleDarknetThread(Darknet(), image_path)
        darknet_instance_2 = SimpleDarknetThread(Darknet(), image_path)
        darknet_instance_3 = SimpleDarknetThread(Darknet(), image_path)
        darknet_instance_4 = SimpleDarknetThread(Darknet(), image_path)

        darknet_instance_1.start()
        darknet_instance_2.start()
        darknet_instance_3.start()
        darknet_instance_4.start()

        darknet_instance_1.join()
        darknet_instance_2.join()
        darknet_instance_3.join()
        darknet_instance_4.join()

        print(f"Darknet 1 output: {darknet_instance_1.output}")
        print(f"Darknet 2 output: {darknet_instance_2.output}")
        print(f"Darknet 3 output: {darknet_instance_3.output}")
        print(f"Darknet 4 output: {darknet_instance_4.output}")


class SimpleDarknetThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, darknet, image_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.darknet = darknet
        self.image_path = image_path
        self.output = None

    def run(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.output = self.darknet.process(self.image_path)
        print(f"Required time: {(time.time() - start_time):.2f} s")


if __name__ == "main":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Never used pexpect before. But by reading the GitHub forums, they say pexpect is incompatible with multithreading and that its better to switch to _multiprocessing_ if you want to run multiple shells at once. [Here's the source](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/369) in case you want to read it yourself (the post is still open, meaning it wasn't fixed until now). There might be some GIL problems under the hood of this module.

Comment: Why use this over Darknet's python wrapper?  Are you using CPU-only Darknet?  I'm guessing so, because of your huge 70 ms processing time per image.  With a GPU, you'd probably be getting sub-10 millisecond processing.  But either way, this seems to be a strange way of processing multiple images at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have zero knowledge when it comes to "pexpect".  From the code you posted, it seems you are spawning multiple CLI instances of Darknet.

The main issue is the thing that takes the longest time to run, is loading the weights into the GPU.  And now you've multiplied this time by 4!

The other issue is that loading the weights consumes a lot of vram, something which exists in limited quantity.  Depending on the configuration you are using, and the dimensions for which you've trained, you may not have enough vram to load 4 independent copies of your neural network at once.

Assuming the vram problem isn't an issue, let me show you why loading 4 copies at once to process exactly 1 image each won't help.

When either Darknet or DarkHelp runs, it outputs the length of time it takes to load the neural network.  In my case, I'll load the usual 80-class MSCOCO network which displays the following on the GPU hardware I have:

```
Done! Loaded 162 layers from weights-file 
-> loading network took 1335.175 milliseconds
```

Processing an image then takes 53.691 additional milliseconds:

```
#1/1: loading "artwork/dog.jpg"
-> prediction took 53.691 milliseconds
```

So if all the images are the same dimensions, processing should take more-or-less the same amount of time.  Meaning 54 milliseconds each.  Total time to load this network and process 4 images is 1335 + 54 * 4 = 1551 milliseconds.

Now if I do this in 4 calls to the Darknet or DarkHelp CLI, we're multiplying the load time by 4, giving us (1335 + 54) * 4 = 5556 milliseconds.

So obviously, loading multiple copies of Darknet or DarkHelp, and processing 1 image in each instance is not the right solution.

Instead, if you are using python, what you should be doing is loading the weights once.  Then, make repeated calls to process as many images as you need.  Both Darknet and DarkHelp have a python API.

- Darknet python API:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet/tree/master/src-python
- DarkHelp python API:  https://github.com/stephanecharette/DarkHelp/tree/master/src-python

The API should be easy enough to use given the example.py file.  For example:

```
dh = DarkHelp.CreateDarkHelpNN(cfg_filename, names_filename, weights_filename)
DarkHelp.SetThreshold(dh, 0.35)
DarkHelp.SetAnnotationLineThickness(dh, 1)
DarkHelp.PredictFN(dh, "page_1.png".encode("utf-8"))
json = DarkHelp.GetPredictionResults(dh)
```

So the idea is you'd call `Predict()` or `PredictFN()` followed by `GetPredictionsResults()` as many times as you have images.  But in each case, you'd only load the weights once, even if you're processing thousands of images.

Now if you want to get fancy and you have enough vram on your GPU, you could instantiate multiple Darknet or DarkHelp objects.  Each of which loads the weights.  And then you can use each one in parallel to process multiple images at once.  But the thing you need to watch is your vram usage.  Running `nvidia-smi` should tell you how much vram each instance is using and whether you can instantiate another copy.

Other performance hints are in the YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#fps

Copied here in case that URL goes down:

- Probably the biggest impact on FPS is the configuration you use. See [What configuration file should I use?](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#configuration_template) at the top of this FAQ.
- The network dimensions. The larger the dimensions, the slower it will be. See [Does the network have to be perfectly square?](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#square_network) and [What is the optimal network size?](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#optimal_network_size) at the top of this FAQ.
- Whether your video frames or images need to be resized due to the network dimensions you are using. [Resizing video frames is very expensive.](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2021-10-16_darknet_fps/#resize)
- The hardware you use. [Don't attempt to use the CPU.](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#cpu_vs_gpu) Get a GPU that has CUDA support.
- Whether you are using [Darknet+CUDA, or OpenCV DNN+CUDA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFYV2uPt-XI).
- Prefer the C or C++ API over using Python. ("[Statistically, C++ is 400 times faster than Python [...]](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20much%20faster%20is%20C%2B%2B%20than%20python))

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have one more question.
After implemented darknet python API I have new trouble. The result is not the same as when I used a darknet detector. Did you have any problem with this?

Comment: The python API uses the C API.  The results should be *exactly* the same.

Comment: Not really. Darknet detector test use with standard part for network preparing this part 
    calculate_binary_weights(net);
I try to proceed with network value but in Python i only have the pointer of the network so I don't have any idea for a solution. The only idea is to add a new method calculate_binary_weights_ptr in detector.c .

Comment: If you have a file called "detector.c" then you are using an out-of-date and unsupported repo.  Please switch to the new Darknet/YOLO repo.  The AlexeyAB repo has been unsupported since July 2021:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#which_repos_to_use_and_avoid